# Macbook pro audio out + built in speaker

Tags: audio, macbook

This may be a stupid question, but does anyone know if it is possible to output audio from both the 3.5 audio out as well as the inbuilt speakers on a MBP model MB133*/A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically for a laptop soundcard that has both internal speakers and a headphone out, there is only one amplifier, and the output can either go to the speakers or headphones, not both. Often the switching is analog - plugging in the headphone jack physically breaks the circuit going to the speaker while connecting the signal to the jack.

Comment: Cheers for the response. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an **aggregate** audio device that contains the outputs for those two outputs stuck together into one device you can select in the audio settings.  This will theoretically work.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh1096.html

You'll find info in the mac help and a little tutorial here:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3956

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the above, however for some reason the internal speakers and the headphone output display as only one device - the source just changes when I plug in / pull out the audio cable :( Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: I would guess it is not possible then.  It may be hardwired to act as the same device.  See here as well http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=424092